# Kotlin - Count the number of items from the List of data class based on field value

Tags: kotlin, collections

What is the easiest or cleaner way of counting the total number of item from list where value is equal to 'condition'?

Lets say I have this data class

```
data class Sample(
    val status: String = "Sample"
){
     var isSelected: Boolean = false
}
```

I need the total number of item from a `List<Sample>` where `isSelected` is `true`. Doing for loops is boring for this and wanted to make it shorter.
TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `count` method for this:

```kt
list.count { it.isSelected }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) for this:

```
yourList.filter { item.isSelected }.size
```

Or more compressed :

```
yourList.count { item.isSelected }
```

Comment: Any difference on `currentList.count { it.isSelected }`?